# How to calculate the average of selected columns across a row in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Say I have a dataframe like this where not every column is of a numeric type

```
  val df_test = Seq((1,2,"A"),(1,2,"B"),(3,4,"C")).toDF("num1","num2","let3")
```

[image]

how would I create a new column called "avg_col" that selects specific columns by name, (in this case num1 and num2) and takes the row wise average of them.

I would like to pass in the columns to be selected as a list.

Thank you and have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it there is a specific row wise function, but you can always do this:

```
val df_test = Seq((1,2,4,"A"),(1,2,3, "B"),(3,4,5,"C")).toDF("num1","num2","num3", "let3")

// +----+----+----+----+
// |num1|num2|num3|let3|
// +----+----+----+----+
// |   1|   2|   4|   A|
// |   1|   2|   3|   B|
// |   3|   4|   5|   C|
// +----+----+----+----+

// I will assume that you have a list of columns that you want to average.

val cols = List("num1", "num3", "num3")

// Map list of columns to [Column]

val test_cols = cols.map(name => col(name))

val avg_func = test_cols.foldLeft(lit(0)){(x, y) => x+y}/test_cols.length

df_test.withColumn("avg_col", avg_func).show(false)

// +----+----+----+----+------------------+
// |num1|num2|num3|let3|avg_col           |
// +----+----+----+----+------------------+
// |1   |2   |4   |A   |3.0               |
// |1   |2   |3   |B   |2.3333333333333335|
// |3   |4   |5   |C   |4.333333333333333 |
// +----+----+----+----+------------------+
```

Comment: Ok thanks but how would I do this passing in a list of columns rather than hard coding the column names?

Comment: I just updated the answer to take into account passing in a list of columns.

Comment: I'm getting all nulls with the new avg_col for some reason. Hm

Comment: do you have lit and col functions imported?

Comment: I just updated code with another column, works just fine. BTW, I'm using spark version 2.4.3.

Comment: I think the issue is that I have an array of column names that aren't of type col. How would I map col to an array before passing it into the averageFunc?

Comment: Try now, I've updated the answer to take into account column mapping.

Answer (score 0):

The row wise average function (with null handling) is as follows:

- Average of 1,2,3 should be 1+2+3/3=2
- Average of 0,0,0 should be 0+0+0/3=0
- Average of 3,3,0 should be 3+3+0/3=2
- Average of 8,null,4 should be 8+4/2=6
- Average of null,null,4 should be 4/1=4
- Average of null,null,null should be null

Code-

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val df_test = spark.read.option("header",true)
      .csv("src/test/resources/row_wise_average.csv")

//csv contents for testing
//num1,num2,num3,let3
//1,2,4,"A"
//1,2,3,"B"
//3,4,5,"C"
//8,,4,"D"
//,,4,"E"
//,,,"F"
//0,0,0,"G"
//3,3,0,"H"

df_test.show()

+----+----+----+----+
|num1|num2|num3|let3|
+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   4|   A|
|   1|   2|   3|   B|
|   3|   4|   5|   C|
|   8|null|   4|   D|
|null|null|   4|   E|
|null|null|null|   F|
|   0|   0|   0|   G|
|   3|   3|   0|   H|
+----+----+----+----+

def columnAverage(colList: List[String]): Column = {
  var denominator = lit(0)
  var numerator = lit(0)
  colList.foreach{colName =>
    denominator = denominator + when(col(colName).isNull,lit(0)).otherwise(lit(1))
    numerator = numerator + when(col(colName).isNull,lit(0)).otherwise(col(colName))
  }
  when(denominator === lit(0),lit(null)).otherwise(numerator/denominator)
}

df_test.withColumn("avg_col",columnAverage(List("num1", "num2", "num3"))).show(false)

+----+----+----+----+------------------+
|num1|num2|num3|let3|avg_col           |
+----+----+----+----+------------------+
|1   |2   |4   |A   |2.3333333333333335|
|1   |2   |3   |B   |2.0               |
|3   |4   |5   |C   |4.0               |
|8   |null|4   |D   |6.0               |
|null|null|4   |E   |4.0               |
|null|null|null|F   |null              |
|0   |0   |0   |G   |0.0               |
|3   |3   |0   |H   |2.0               |
+----+----+----+----+------------------+
```